# Outlook 2003 Drag & Drop inbox to outbox confusing behaviour

Tags: email, outlook, office-2003

I recently received a mail directed to a whole bunch of people which I accidentally dropped in the outbox (I think) instead of an archive directory where I wanted to put it.

The mail disappeared and moved to my sent items, which is scary because I don't want to send it to all these people. However when I try the same thing again with another mail from a friend directed just to me... nothing happens as it stays in the outbox.

Firstly: no one reported receiving the mail twice, first the original and then from me.
Secondly: this makes me wonder if I just dropped it into the Sent Items directly instead of the outbox and just feared the worst.

So basically the question: IF I drag and drop a mail from the inbox to the outbox, what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will happen - Outbox is just an eye candy. A message can be submitted from any folder; Outlook moves messages to the Outbox just to avoid confusing the users.